# Age range calculation with Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, calculation

How do I display the month-year on the date-picker for the 0-2 age range only? 
How can I write this code?

```
For Example:
15 July 2017
15 July 2019
Total: 730 days
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `yearRange` , `minDate` and `maxDate` in  Datepicker for selecting date between year range i.e `2017-2019` .  i.e :

```js
$('#d1 , #d2').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '2017:2019', //<--setting range 2 years
    minDate: new Date(2017, 6, 15), //<--min date i.e 15/7/2017
    maxDate: new Date(2019, 6, 15) // <--max date i.e 15/7/2019
});


$(".btn").on("click",function(){
//getting date value from datepicker
var start = $('#d1').datepicker("getDate");
var end = $('#d2').datepicker("getDate");

 var days = (end- start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
 console.log(days);
 
$("#total").html("Total  : " +days);

});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    
       Date1: <input type="text" name="ab" id="d1" />
        <br/>
        Date2: <input type="text" name="ab1" id="d2" />
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="calculate" class="btn"/>
        
        <div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: Great , Try to accept this answer if it solved your problem.